# ChartJs error in displaying my array data

Tags: angular, chart.js

I have an error when I display my array with chartjs. its does not display my values ​​in the graph but its does display them as a label.

[myChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjm5e.png)

```
  var data  = {

      labels: [this.dataTime],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Custom Label Name',
        backgroundColor: gradient,
        pointBackgroundColor: 'white',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#911215',
        data: [this.dataPrice],
      }]
  };
```

Comment: please share stackblitz link to know more in detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your chart it's treating the labels als multiline since it's an array in an array.

If you remove the array brackets around the labels variable and the array brackets around the data variable it should work.

So you would get:

```
var data  = {
      labels: this.dataTime,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Custom Label Name',
        backgroundColor: gradient,
        pointBackgroundColor: 'white',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#911215',
        data: this.dataPrice,
      }]
  };
```

Comment: Despite a late reply, thank you for helping me